# wpf wrappanel binding to a list

Tags: wpf, binding

In wpf have a wrappanel that is bound to a list of classes

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserEntryItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ItemTextEntry/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
   </ScrollViewer>
```

For each item in the list I want to display a usercontrol.

The usercontrol requires to know the individual class info but i unsure how to bound that.

So my mainview xmal now looks like the following

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserEntryItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ItemTextEntry LocalUserEntry ="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

My Usercontrol "ItemTextEntry" looks like the following

```
public partial class ItemTextEntry : UserControl
{
    public UserEntry LocalUserEntry
    {
        get { return (UserEntry)GetValue(LocalUserEntryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LocalUserEntryProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocalUserEntryProperty= DependencyProperty.Register("LocalUserEntry", typeof(UserEntry),
        typeof(ItemTextEntry), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new UserEntry()));



    public ItemTextEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

if i put a breakpoint in "public ItemTextEntry()" LocalUserEntry dosnt represent the values in the main list

Thanks

Comment: What's the `UserEntryItems` here

Comment: its the name of the list

Comment: You already have the user control *local:ItemTextEntry* . What do you exactly need ?

Comment: how do i pass the contents of the listitem to the usercontrol

Comment: Alreadt you're passing the contents.  Your code should work now.  Are you facing any issue in it.

Comment: *Contents of listitem* meaning? Do you mean the data contained in the properties of your class?

Comment: yes the list contains instances of a class, i want a usercontrol for each instance and for wpf to pass the instance of the class to the usercontrol

Comment: You already, will have a *local:ItemTextEntry* for each item in *UserEntryItems*

Comment: so in the actual usercontrol code how do i get at the properties in the individual class

Comment: @user1603332 Is that answer helpful for you?

Comment: the LocalUserEntry is still always blank in my usercontrol

Answer (score 3):

If your `UserEntryItem` class has a property called `Name`and your usercontrol `ItemTextEntry` has a dependency property called `Text` (one which you can bind to..),
your xaml would look like:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserEntryItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                // The DataContext here is at the level of each individual item in the UserEntryItems list
                <local:ItemTextEntry Text="{Binding Name}"/> // This can be used to display the data from the properties in your class
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemTemplate` is for styling how the content of your **data item** appears when you pass **List of items**.

Provided code should work.  Don't know Where you went wrong.

Let me post a sample based on the given code for your reference.

**MainWindow.xaml (as provided)**

```
 <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding UserEntryItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:ItemTextEntry/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs (includes ViewModel)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<MyClass> mc = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
        mc.Add(new MyClass() { Text1 = "test1", Text2 = "test2" });
        mc.Add(new MyClass() { Text1 = "test1", Text2 = "test2" });
        mc.Add(new MyClass() { Text1 = "test1", Text2 = "test2" });
        mc.Add(new MyClass() { Text1 = "test1", Text2 = "test2" });
        mc.Add(new MyClass() { Text1 = "test1", Text2 = "test2" });

        MainViewModel mv = new MainViewModel() { UserEntryItems = mc };

        this.DataContext = mv;

    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> UserEntryItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
}
public class MyClass
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
}
```

**ItemTextEntry.xaml (sample one)**

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```